# K fold cross validation clarification

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

I don't know if I understood K-fold CV correctly. Here I will explain briefly what I am trying to do. 
I have a matrix **X** which I split into 3 folds, 2 training **$X_1$**, **$X_2$** and one testing **$X_3$**:

[image]

**Step 1**

- I concatenate **$X_1$** and **$X_2$** so I have **$X_{1,2}$**, then I generate a **$Y_{1,2}$**. I compute the $\hat{\beta_{1,2}}$ from the formula: $\hat{\beta_{1,2}}=(X^tX+\lambda I_p)^{-1}X^t Y$ and I compute the predicted $\hat{Y_{1,2}}=X_{1,2}\hat{\beta_{1,2}}$

**step 2** I reshuffle. Then I have:

[image]

I do the same as in *step 1*, I compute **$X_{1,3}$**, **$Y_{1,3}$**,  $\hat{\beta_{1,3}}$ and $\hat{Y_{1,3}}$

Then I reshuffle again and get:

[image]

And I compute again:  **$X_{2,3}$**, **$Y_{2,3}$**,  $\hat{\beta_{2,3}}$ and $\hat{Y_{2,3}}$

**step 3** Computing the error **(This is the part where I'm not quite sure if it is correct)**
The formula for the square loss is: $L(Y)=(Y-\hat{Y})^2$

Would then these be correct:

$L(Y_1)=(Y_{1,2}-\hat{Y_{2,3}})^2$,

$L(Y_2)=(Y_{1,3}-\hat{Y_{2,3}})^2$,

$L(Y_3)=(Y_{2,3}-\hat{Y_{1,2}})^2$

**step 4** Calculating the mean of the above errors
 $CV = \frac{1}{n}\sum_j^n[L(Y)]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do a mini example with 6 samples:

Let $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$ be three sets:
$$
X_1 = \{x_1,x_2\}\\
X_2 = \{x_3,x_4\}\\
X_3 = \{x_5,x_6\}\\
$$

Each $x_i$ here is a vector. Judging from your previous question, this will be a **1x15** vector.

You also have:
$$
Y_1 = \{y_1, y_2\}\\
Y_2 = \{y_3, y_4\}\\
Y_3 = \{y_5, y_6\}\\
$$

Those $y_i$ are single values.

Then you create three sets by merging those three folds in different combinations:
$$
X_{1,2} = X_1 \cup X_2\\
X_{1,3} = X_1 \cup X_3\\
X_{2,3} = X_2 \cup X_3
$$

Once you train the three models you have $\beta_{1,2}$, $\beta_{1,3}$ and $\beta_{2,3}$.

Here is the important part.
To calculate the predictions you do:
$$
\hat{Y_1} = X_1\beta_{2,3}
$$

Similarly for the other two:
$$
\hat{Y_2} = X_2\beta_{1,3}\\
\hat{Y_3} = X_3\beta_{1,2}
$$

Then your error is:
$$
L(y_1) = (y_1 - \hat{y_1})^2\\
L(y_2) = (y_2 - \hat{y_2})^2\\
L(y_3) = (y_3 - \hat{y_3})^2\\
L(y_4) = (y_4 - \hat{y_4})^2\\
L(y_5) = (y_5 - \hat{y_5})^2\\
L(y_6) = (y_6 - \hat{y_6})^2\\
CV=\frac{1}{n}\sum_i[L(y_i)]
$$

Note that $\hat{y_1}$ and $\hat{y_2}$ are samples from your matrix $\hat{Y_1}$. $\hat{y_3}$ and $\hat{y_4}$ are part of $\hat{Y_2}$. $\hat{y_5}$ and $\hat{y_6}$ is in $\hat{Y_3}$.

Answer (score 1):

I find your notation a bit hard but I think I get it, additionally I think you are slightly off.

Once you have calculated $\hat \beta_{12}$ you want to use this to create predicted values for the values of $Y$ that were not in your training data, Lets call this $\hat Y_{3 \mid 1,2}$ . For clarity that is to say the predicted values of $Y_3$ after fitting a model using data from $X_{12}$ . You then calculate your error as $ (Y_3 - \hat Y_{3 \mid 1,2}) ^ 2$. Your last line is then correct that you then repeat this for all your folds of data and take the mean across all your predicted errors.